# Why is Eclipse "Searching for main types" when I just told it what to run?

Tags: eclipse

In response to
Right-click -> Run As -> Java Application,

Eclipse occasionally pauses to search for all the main types in the workspace.  Why is the necessary, since I just told it what type to run?  Is there a way to suppress it?  (In a workspace with many open projects it's very time-consuming.)

This is with Mars 4.5.2

thanks,
Jon

Comment: I noticed this as well, even when I just ran the application 5 min ago and it has a run configuration. I think its a bug as it didn't happen on versions of eclipse I used until a year ago

Comment: I have similar problem, I tried cleaning the entire workspace but doesn't works. Any other idea?

Comment: Same problem, are you importing the package Stream for functional issues?

Answer (score 2):

Set up a run configuration and define which main type to run. This tells eclipse which main class to run when you run that particular config and it doesn't look for any other main type.

Answer (score 2):

I found the same problem, Eclipsed stuck on

```
Searching for main types...
```

and specifically on

```
Locating Java matches...
```

I have not be able to solve the problem cleaning workspace or reinstalling (downloading) a new version of Eclipse. 
I am using:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers    
Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200
```

Finally, the solution, I identificate the problem in a class that I wrote in a project, this problem occurs only when min a class I have the following import:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
```

Deleted that line the problem disappear.